# Windows 10 - How to share a folder for media streaming

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing, dlna, smart-tv

I recently moved my movies to a different location on my PC and the sharing broke. I tried to recreate it using the Windows 10 share feature and in principle it works - I see them on my phone in network locations.

But my TV does not.

I found this old post https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/fr6gjn/extreme_frustration_with_libraries_network/
which describes my issue almost exactly.

I suspect the culprit may be `WMPNetworkSvc`.
I tried to Get-ACL and Set-ACL in Powershell but it still doesn'tt work.

Anyone could help?

At this moment the only truly shared to TV folders are in `C:\Users\Public`

The way I set permissions:
D:\Videos > right click > properties > sharing tab > share > add myself and everyone RW

D:\Videos > right click > properties > sharing tab > advanced sharing > check 'share this folder'
And here I added Two shares named Movies and Videos, Administrators and everyone set to full control

I also thought of making a directory junction (I called it `D`) from Public to D and it kinda worked - If on the TV I now go to Videos > Folders > Public Videos > D > Videos I can see just the directories I have my movies, but not the video files themselves. And on windows the videos do not have share option (or I didn't find one)

EDIT 19.10.2023
Since Microsoft is not eager to help I'm trying on my own.

I put some videos (named by the folder) in each public folder and also in Music, Videos and Pictures library folders. On the tv (LG webOS) I see:

- My PC

  - all videos

    - music.mp4
    - pictures.mp4
    - public_videos.mp4
  - folders

    - Public Videos

      - public_videos.mp4

This tells me that permissions itself are not enough. And what is also worth noting is that TV shows a video stored in Pictures library but not the one in Public Pictures.
When I was moving my movies to a different drive I also moved the library folder Videos and yet it is not visible on the TV.

I also copied ~/Pictures to ~/Copied Pictures and the video from Pictures, that was visible on the TV, was not visible when it was located in Copied Pictures. (shared for everyone R)

Then I ran `mklink /D "Videos" D:\Videos` in my user's directory and that made the TV to show `folders > Videos > all my movies' directories` but no files in them! I believe the TV recognises the folders also by name - it has to be Videos, which is weird considering they pop up in 'folders' on TV...

mklinking ~/Videos to ~/Desktop/Test (same drive) also shows only directories even if every thing is shared to everyone.

Comment: What does your TV see from your computer? With what credentials does it try to access the share? You could also use a safer solution such as a free streaming media server like for example [Serviio](https://serviio.org/) that doesn't depend on network shares.

Comment: TV Sees only the public folders. They have the default access setting (I think RW) the one I shared I set rw for everyone without success

Comment: Try to add RW permissions also for the `Guest` account, which is distinct from `Everyone`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. The only thing that is visible on the TV is the public folder (vid, pics... - all of them). The serviio will probably help, but I have a proof that windows can also do it, just not sure how to apply it to a different folder. I also tried symlinks but its not picked up by TV either.

Comment: It's most likely a permissions problem. Did you set the share permissions in the two places: The file-system and the share definition (these are two separate places to look at).

Comment: I agree its a permissions problem. I just got off the chat with Microsoft help, unfortunately the helpdesk person could not figure it out and escalated the issue, they are supposed to call tomorrow. I updated the question with what I found out so far

Comment: In *Properties > Sharing > Advanced Sharing*, click Permissions and verify that Everyone has the Read permission and nothing under Deny.

Comment: Yes, Everyone and Administrators both have everything set to allow already :(

Comment: The microsoft help and community didn't help at all, just checked the basics and tried to appear doing something about it 

Comment: Last try : Set again the permissions of the folder for `Everyone` and `Guest`, but do it via *Properties > Security > Advanced > Change permissions* and check "Replace all child object permission entries".

Comment: Ok, didn't help either. My new theory is that the `Everyone` permission is enough but the webOs app does some additional filtering. I wrote a support request email to LG, maybe it will reach some technician...

Comment: In the meantime, a streaming media server will solve the problem for now and ever.